# Problem with getting user created at and geo full name from the Twitter API using Python

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

For my thesis, I am currently trying to gather data from Twitter via their API. I am fairly new to coding, but I managed to get out some variables, but two do not seem to work. These are user created at (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user) and geo full name (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/expansions).

The code attached is working. I already tried things like tweet.geo['full_name'] or tweet.user.created_at but these do not work. Can someone explain how I can add the missing two variables?

```
import tweepy
import config
import pandas as pd

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.ACADEMIC_BEARER_TOKEN)

query = 'query -is:retweet'

start_time = '2021-01-30T00:00:00Z'
end_time = '2022-01-30T00:00:00Z'

response = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, max_results=100, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time,
                                    tweet_fields=['text', 'id', 'created_at', 'referenced_tweets', 'public_metrics'],
                                    place_fields=['full_name'], user_fields=['created_at'],
                                    expansions=['geo.place_id', 'author_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id'])

df = pd.DataFrame()

for tweet in response.data:
    df = df.append({'text' : tweet.text, 'author_id' : tweet.author_id, 'tweet_id' : tweet.id,
                    'tweet.created_at' : tweet.created_at, 'in_reply_to_user_id' : tweet.in_reply_to_user_id,
                    'public_metrics' : tweet.public_metrics, 'referenced_tweets' : tweet.referenced_tweets,
                    'place_name' : tweet.geo}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only the id of the expanded objects (`user` and `place` in your case) in the `response.data`. The content of these objects is located in the `response.includes`.

The response of the Twitter API looks like that:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "...",
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "geo": {
                "place_id": "01a9a39529b27f36"
            },
        }
    ],
    "includes": {
        "places": [
            {
                "id": "01a9a39529b27f36",
                "full_name": "Manhattan, NY"
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "2244994945",
                "created_at": "..."
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

So you have to get the author (/place) id in each tweet and, then, use this id to find the corresponding user (/place) in the included ones.